# eslint No Unsafe Assignment Rule

Tags: typescript, eslint

I have this HTTP test that tests simple successful output from a function called echo.

```
describe('HTTP tests using Jest', () => {
  test('Test successful echo', () => {
    const res = request(
      'GET',
            `${url}:${port}/echo`,
            {
              qs: {
                echo: 'Hello',
              }
            }
    );

    const bodyObj = JSON.parse(res.body as string);
    expect(res.statusCode).toBe(OK);
    expect(bodyObj).toEqual('Hello');
  });
```

When I try to lint I get @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment error on the line below

> const bodyObj = JSON.parse(res.body as string);

Is there a way to ignore this rule entirely? How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either ignore for this line with:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
const bodyObj = JSON.parse(res.body as string);
```

Or for the whole file:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment*/
```

Or if you want to ignore this rule entirely, you can check your eslint config and set

```
{
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment": "warn" // or "off" if you want to disable it
  }
}
```

But if you want to actually fix this error, you should [avoid assigning a variable of type `any`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unsafe-assignment/) to a variable, in this case, you have [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), for example, you can set `unknown` as type:

```
const bodyObj = JSON.parse(res.body as string) as unknown;
```

Or maybe better if you set your actual `res.body` type

```
const bodyObj = JSON.parse(res.body as string) as MyTypeOrInterface;
```